# Make hovered menu stick long enough to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a nav bar with submenus but when I open the submenu I am not able to click on the list. The hovered list isn't staying open for me to click on it.

```js
$('.one').hover(function(){
  $(this).next().show();
 }, function(){
  $(this).next().hide();
 });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.yo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 100%;
  top: 30%;
}

.yo a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="one">Link 1</a>
      <div class="yo">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
      <a href="#" class="one">Link 2</a>
      <div class="yo">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
     </div>
      <a href="#" class="one">Link 3</a>
      <div class="yo">
      <a href="#">Link 7</a>
      <a href="#">Link 8</a>
      <a href="#">Link 9</a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on ***Dropdown***--> Hover over ***Link 1*** and now I want to select ***Link 1*** in the sub-submenu that opens when you hover. Is there anyways I can keep the link open long enough to click the link.

Comment: Notice how the "dropdown" link has everything within it's DIV and just with css :hover it is showing/hiding the menu. You need to put the button "one" and submenu "yo" both in one div and do css :hover on the div. No need jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the "dropdown" link has everything within it's DIV and just with css :hover it is showing/hiding the menu. You need to put the button "one" and submenu "yo" both in one div and do css :hover on the div. No need jquery.

The html:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#" class="one">Link 1</a>
        <div class="yo">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#" class="one">Link 2</a>
        <div class="yo">
          <a href="#">Link 4</a>
          <a href="#">Link 5</a>
          <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#" class="one">Link 3</a>
        <div class="yo">
          <a href="#">Link 7</a>
          <a href="#">Link 8</a>
          <a href="#">Link 9</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add this css:

```
.submenu:hover .yo {
  display: block;
}
```

Remove the JQuery hover.

[Here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajz6k3n7/)

Comment: Try hovering Link 1 and then try to click on the other Link 1 that appears, you will not be able to unfortunately